# Copying certain contents of a file to another

Tags: c

I am trying to limit the amount of lines I copy over to a file to x amount. I know how to copy the files, but how would I limit it, for example, 10 lines.

Code:

```
char buf[BUFSIZ];
  int outft, inft,fileread;

  if((outft = open("TMPFILE3", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0644))==-1){
    perror("open"); 
  }     

  inft = open("TMPFILE", O_RDONLY);
  if(inft >0){
    fileread = read(inft, buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    write(outft, buf, fileread);
    close(inft);
  }        
  close(outft);
```

Comment: Use `fdopen()`, then you can just use `fgets()` and `fputs()` 10 times. Otherwise, you'll have to count the newlines.

Comment: Note that your code continues to use `outft` even after reporting failure to open the file.  `perror()` does not exit the program.

Comment: @Axalo The problem is I am copying all of the lines, and I want to just copy ten.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths Ok, I'll try that. Thank you!